# Xamarin Forms - A card holding a ListView inside has a height very large

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, nested

I have a ListView with items and one of the items is a DataTemplate with a ListView inside of it.

The issue here is that this DataTemplate is renderred very high without any need.

Here is a link to a screenshot of the outcome:

[image: This is how it looks like.]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBxpb.jpg

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyNotes.ViewModels"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyNotes.Converters"
    xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:MyNotes.Behavior"
    xmlns:selectors="clr-namespace:MyNotes.Selectors"
    x:Class="MyNotes.Views.MainView">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <converters:CollectionEmptyConverter x:Key="CollectionEmptyConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StringTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding}"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultItemTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame OutlineColor="Black" Margin="10">
                    <Grid Margin="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label Text="Unknow Item" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TodoItemTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame OutlineColor="Black" Margin="10">
                    <Grid Margin="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Content}" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame OutlineColor="Black">
                    <Grid Margin="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                                    Margin="0,10,0,0"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StringTemplate}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <selectors:ItemTypeSelector x:Key="ItemTypeSelector"
                                    TodoItemTemplate="{StaticResource TodoItemTemplate}"
                                    ListItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemTemplate}"/>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Text="No notes yet. Add some."
                    IsVisible="{Binding Collection, Converter={StaticResource CollectionEmptyConverter}}"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
                        IsVisible="{Binding Collection, Converter={StaticResource CollectionEmptyConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTypeSelector}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I tried a lot of solutions without luck, e.g.:

```
1. I can't set the height of the listview
2. HasUnevenRows didn't work for me
3. I have rows of different height so setting RowHeight is not an option
4. Tried to investigate using behaviors and found nothing to assist me.
```

I have read in several places that the issue is most likely to be related to the fact that I have a ListView inside a ListView (in the DataTemplate).
Since it is a collection of items where some items can have a list of items inside I don't see how else I can solve this.

Any help direction will be great.

Thanks

**Edit:**
I've checked a theory with a much smaller example

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
              BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
    <Label Text="bla bla bla"
           Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

In this example I assumed the listview would take only the place needed but it doesn't, it takes the whole app height and I can't event see the text "bla bla bla".
Why is this behavior???

Comment: The first answer here describes the reason for this behavior. ListView is setup to fill all available space by default. You'd either need to set its size, or the size of its container, to a specific value. You could consider doing this dynamically at runtime, if that height is going to be variable. Ultimately, the reason it works this way is because it's generally considered bad design to have nested listviews. You may want to think a bit harder about the interaction model here.

Answer (score 1):

**For your second question:**

In your code snippet, the height of the first row is set to `Auto` which means that

> the object should be sized to the available size in layout so that the
>   first row will size to fit its content.

And the ListView is in this row, in that case, the ListView will auto fill with the whole screen to fit its content.

The second row is set to `*`,which means that

> after the auto rows are calculated, the row gets part of the
>   remaining height.

So after the auto rows are calculated , the remaining height for your label is 0.This is why you can't even see the text "bla bla bla".

I verify this conclusion by view the `ListView` and `Label's` height in code behind.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            this.SizeChanged += MainPage_SizeChanged; 

        }

        private void MainPage_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ListView height
            Double a = myListView.Height;

            //Label height
            Double b = myLabel.Height;

        }
    }
```

Here is the result:[image: Height of <code>ListView</code> and <code>Label</code>]

Comment: Thanks, I know that, I just ask why did they gave the ListView extra height and not the height the content needs as it is measurable. It has been done in WPF so it can be done here as well to give us better experience.

Comment: In my opinion,`ListView` is not intended to always size itself to just fit its contents. It is intended to be a scrolling container that will be able to display all its cells, by scrolling, not by initially sizing itself. The number of cells will never affect its height.So, when your set `auto` to the `RowDefinition` , the ListView will auto fill with the whole screen to fit its content instead of give the height the content needs.

Comment: I just checked how it behaves in WPF and I just noticed it behaves worse. After your answer and seeing how the ListView behaves in WPF I understand your opinion (and Xamarin impl.) is probebly the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my first question "ANy help direction will be great".
I found a github project in this [link](https://github.com/andreinitescu/XFItemsControl) that does the job pretty good.
It gives me an ItemsControl which I can assign a source and an item template. I wrapped it in a ScrollView and got a ListView which works as expected.

Here is a sample usage:

```
<ScrollView>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <controls:ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
                           BackgroundColor="Beige">
            <controls:ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentView>
                        <Frame OutlineColor="Black" HasShadow="True" IsClippedToBounds="True" Margin="10">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                <ScrollView>
                                    <controls:ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding InnerCollection}"
                                                   Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </ScrollView>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </ContentView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:ItemsControl>
        <!--<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
              BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>-->
        <Label Text="bla bla bla"
           Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

As for my second question "Why is this behavior???" - I still don't know the answer but at least I can make progress